# Python - why importing a submodule makes the package visible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, python-import

The code below prints wx.ACCEL_NORMAL alright

```
import wx.gizmos

# import wx # uncommenting this the warning is eliminated

print wx.ACCEL_NORMAL # Pycharm warns: "Cannot find reference 'ACCEL_NORMAL'
# in imported module wx" but finds it alright when i run it
```

Two questions:

1. How come it sees wx ?
2. Why it warns ? Is it related to a wx (2.8.12.1) peculiarity or is it to be expected or is it a Pycharm bug or... ?

EDIT:

probably a wx thing as below issues no warnings:

```
import os.path

print os.name
```

but then Q1 still stands

EDIT2:

changing the import to

```
import wx.gizmos as gizmos
```

I get the expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/utumno/.PyCharm40/config/scratches/scratch", line 5, in <module>
    print wx.ACCEL_NORMAL # Pycharm warns: "Cannot find reference 'ACCEL_NORMAL'
NameError: name 'wx' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `import wx.gizmos` imports the `wx` package first (storing it in `sys.modules['wx']` if not loaded before, then also imports the `wx.gizmos` module and makes it an attribute of the `sys.modules['wx']` object. Python then binds `wx` to the `sys.modules['wx']`.

As such, you end up with the global name `wx` in your code, through which you can reference `wx.gizmos`.

PyCharm's warning can be ignored here; the static analysis the IDE uses should be taking into account that importing `wx.gizmos` makes `wx` available. That this fails for `wx.gizmos` and works for `os.path` could be due to any number of factors; perhaps the PyCharm developers hardcoded `os` handling into the analyser (since importing `os.path` is so common), or the `wx` namespace is implemented as a C extension which means that static analysis has to rely on pre-computed maps of available names, and perhaps the `wx` map is not loaded here.

Comment: Hmmm - sounds like a Pycharm bug - cause uncommenting import wx the warning is gone - so when I issue `import wx` it does the right thing. Worth a bug report. I am sure your answer covers my second edit :)

Comment: Hmm - all this info is missing from https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement - any link where this is documented would be a great addition :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: At issue here is how *PyCharm* analyses your code and provides warnings. That's not a Python issue, that's an issue with the IDE.

Comment: Yep certainly - I mean it is an IDE bug :) (that's for the warning part) . Could you add a link where the resolution of "dot" imports is analyzed as https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement does not contain the info you provided

Comment: The state of documentation on importing in Python 2 is a little... muddled, and I don't have at this time a better reference for you.